# Using pybitcoin to generate a new address (n +1th) from private key

Tags: python, python-2.7, bitcoin

How can I use the pybitcoin library (or for that matter, any other python library), to not only get one address from a private key, but get a next one as well?

```
from pybitcoin import BitcoinPrivateKey
private_key = BitcoinPrivateKey("predefined private key here")
public_key = private_key.public_key()
public_key.address()
```

Will only return the first address. As far as I know, one private key can have infinite number of addresses. Is there an 'index' parameter?